# Angular interceptor, run code after the outgoing request is finished

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient

I got a simple interceptor which checks if an outgoing request is to a specific endpoint type, in this case `events` and `favoriteevents`.

This almost works as expected. The one thing that it's doing wrong is that `this.dispatcher` dispatches before the outgoing request is completed.

How can I change it so that the outgoing request runs first and then the dispatch call is made?

```
import {Injectable, Injector, Optional} from '@angular/core';

import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import {AppConstants} from '@constants/app-constants.constant';
import {DispatcherService} from '@services/dispatcher.service';

@Injectable()

export class EventsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private dispatcher: DispatcherService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const urls = [
      {requestType: 'PUT', snippet: '/events/'},
      {requestType: 'DELETE', snippet: '/events/'},
      {requestType: 'PUT', snippet: '/favoriteevents'},
      {requestType: 'DELETE', snippet: '/favoriteevents'}
    ];

    for (const url of urls) {

      if (req.method === url.requestType || url.requestType === null) {

        if (req.url.indexOf(url.snippet) !== -1) {
          this.dispatcher.dispatch({type: AppConstants.actions.refreshFavoriteEvents});
        }
      }
    }

    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like

```
...
return next.handle(req).pipe( tap( () => {
    if (someCondition) this.dispatcher.dispatch(...);
}) );
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant.